# What do you call a noun phrase that is separated by a comma from the main clause?

Tags: grammar, phrases, construction

Please look at these two sentences:

1. It is serene, **this piece of the Old World**.
2. Word has reached my ears of this Aragorn, son of Arathorn, and I tell you now, I will not bow to this Ranger from the North, **last of a ragged house long bereft of lordship**! (LOTR)

In sentence 1, the phrase "this piece of the Old World" is the deferred subject of the anticipatory "It".

In sentence 2, "last of a ragged house long bereft of lordship" modifies "this Ranger from the North".

In both cases, the phrases do not contain a non-finite verb or a preposition. What kind of construction is it? Sentence 1 is very close to a cleft sentence, but in the reference material there is not a single example where a phrase has been used separated from the main clause by a comma. They are all subordinate clauses.

Could someone clarify what kind of construction this is?

Edit: Reading the comments, I think it is safe to assume that appositives can take the place of subordinate clauses which act as a delayed subject. These are both appositives, then, serving different functions?

Comment: In the former case, it's a [delayed subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188284/delayed-subject-with-short-subject-length) (hopefully that question has some info but there are probably further questions). In the latter case it's unclear whether it's an adjectival phrase, but if it's a noun phrase it's just a regular [appositive](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html), covered in any grammar book and lots of questions here.

Comment: Yes, it is a delayed subject, or deferred subject as some call it. But what is the name for this kind of a phrase? Is there a name to it? The second one seemed like an appositve to me, too, but I was uncertain.

Comment: If "delayed subject" or "appositive" doesn't apply, what more specific thing are you interested in? Is it the "X of Y" construction you are asking about?

Comment: There are too many things going on here , hence it will cover too many grammatical terms like Delayed Subject , Anticipatory It , Parenthetical Phrase , Explanatory Modifier , Introductory Modifier , Irregular Sentence , Etc. Out of all that , the closest is Appositive Noun Phrase [ maybe with a Delayed Subject ] which is used to rename [ & maybe amplify ] some Earlier noun !

Comment: Appositives—noun phrases.

Comment: Does this answer your first question? ["We went swimming later in the afternoon, Jack and I."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167255/we-went-swimming-later-in-the-afternoon-jack-and-i) The second sentence uses a descriptive/expansive (and  nonrestrictive, hence the comma) appositive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It does, thanks.